# How to customize how items are displayed within a ComboBox control?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, combobox

My current task is to populate a ComboBox with dates, have the user pick one and then determine which date he picked.

By default, the ComboBox control uses `Object.ToString` to determine what to display.

My problem is that `DateTime.ToString` shows both date and time. Since the time is irrelevant to my context, I don't want it to be displayed.

Is there a way to customize what the ComboBox will display for each item? Or maybe a way to choose what `DateTime.ToString` will return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I'd use the FormatString-property of the ComboBox-control:

```
myComboBox.FormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Another possibility was the usage of `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` but I think that's more than you need in this case.

Edit: Just for completeness: There's also a `Format`-event

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.Format(DateTime, "[format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)");

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
DateTime.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: I don't want to add strings to the ComboBox items, since it will be a pain to parse the selected item into a DateTime.